# How do I validate WSDLs and SOAP responses?

Tags: validation, soap, wsdl

I am looking to build web services using SOAP. What standards should I follow for formatting WSDLs and SOAP responses and what tools are available to verify I am using the correct standardized formats?

I was thinking something along the lines of W3C's HTML validator but for SOAP and WSDLs. Does any such thing exist?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [WSI](http://ws-i.org/) tools (or other tools that can run the WSI compliance tests). You can also do xml schema validation of the soap messages against the WSDL/XSD that you have so that you can confirm that your service does actually conform to its description.